# Getting error while selecting maps in "Transform XML" azure logic apps connector

Tags: integration, azure-logic-apps

While working with "Transform XML" connector in Azure logic apps. I am getting following error [screen shot of  error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqPsA.png).

```
Could not retrieve values. The filter 'maptype ne 'liquid' is not supported. Only 'MapType' filter is  supported
```

I have create a Basic integration account and upload xslt map. Also I have selected the integration account from Logic app workflow setting.

Comment: It seems there is something wrong in your xslt map, could you please share your xslt map ?

Comment: Hury, I verified xslt map. It is correct. The logic apps runs successfully and gives expected output , It is the Logic App designer ( both Visual Studio and Online) shows this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some test and there is a workaround solution for it. We can click "Code view" and add the map name to it. You can have a try~

[image]